# Google sheet Regexmatch after and before dash

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So i have this sample sentence in A2 like this "umbrela - gray", and now i want to regexmatch the words after and before the "-" with case insensitive, i treid many ways and i cant get there since i dont understand much about regex, what i have now is:

```
regexmatch(A2; CONCATENATE("(?i)"; A3; ))
regexmatch(A2; CONCATENATE("(?i)"; A4; ))
```

The words i want to match live in A3 and A4, and basicly on A3 i want it to match just "umbrela" and on A4 i want it to match just "Gray", but now if i put "gray" in A3 it still returns and i dont want that

Anyone that knows more about regex can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's not clear to me what's your exact goal. What do you mean by "match"? REGEXMATCH returns TRUE or FALSE. If your goal is to have `umbrela` and `gray` displayed in adjacent cells then this is a [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 words with a single hyphen separated, you can use 2 capture groups matching 1 or more word characters each `(\w+)` with [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) in cell A2.

In between you can match a hyphen surrounded by optional whitespace chars using `\s*-\s*`. The `^` and `$` assert the start and the end of the match.

Then use [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) to fill up cell A3 and cell A4.

```
=TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "^(\w+)\s*-\s*(\w+)$"))
```

---

If you want to match more than just word characters except a hyphen, and then must be at least a single non whitespace char except for a hyphen to the left and the right:

```
^([^-]*[^\s-][^-]*?)\s*-\s*([^-]*[^\s-][^-]*)$
```

See the matches at this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D6FUfq/1)

---

[image]